# Query google suggest with jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery

i'm new to jquery and I have heard about the Jquery Autocomplete feature, and the google suggest feature here: `http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=<term>&callback=abc`, I was wondering how I could incorperate the two so that my textbox can suggest things, from google to me.
Any help would be appretiated for me and future users

Comment: Have you even tried to Google? Loads of results about this.

Comment: none relating to exactly what i want, i did plenty of research, if you found something i didn't, please share

Comment: The answer given to you by infadelic is the first link on google. Kind of proves my point to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the
[googleSuggest jQuery Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/googlesuggest-jquery/wiki/GetStarted)